Best way to present a discovered event from the current vicinity
I have this app here where users can find events nearby using Wifi/Bluetooth. This app is intended to be used in large gatherings/crowds. (I can't share much about the project details as I am under NDA.) When the user opens the app, they will be greeted with this screen where the app immediately starts searching for events in their vicinity. I created the background animation as a way to denote the app searching. When an event is discovered, it needs to appear in the center to allow users to join it. The problem I have deciding what they best way to present a discovered event. In these pictures, discovered events show as the green tiles with the event title as the large text and the creator name as the subtext.
(I was struggling to get the post editor to work, so I manually uploaded each image to pasteboard)
The home screen, you'll see this as soon as opening the app: https://pasteboard.co/DOpjEYw2LcLb.gif









1 Event found nearby
Several events found nearby



My thought process is as follows:
The app sticks to a green/white theme, where green is the primary color. Usually I reserve the color green for a primary action. I don't like how all the event cards are colored green, because they all would be vying for the user's attention. When there are too many events, and they trickle down the screen, I find it a bit overwhelming.
I've considered trying a UI similar to Apple's AirDrop or Snapdrop, where a discovered user shows as a circle avatar with their picture/ name in a grid. However, the app doesn't require registered events to include a picture, since that isn't necessary for the functionality. Participants do include their picture, but event creators don't. So a circle avatar with a picture/name wouldn't be necessary here, and if I put the event title inside the circle, I think that would be strange. In that case, an event with a longer title would show a bigger circle which isn't ideal.
My question is what would be the best way to present a discovered event here? Should I lose the background animation and keep the tiles? Or should I go for the AirDrop-style bubbles/avatar presentation? I am happy to answer any questions about the functionality to help clarify as needed. Thanks in advance!

Hi Zach,
Welcome... I would suggest you put the images inline in the post, to prevent link decay, and keep this question more accessible to the community.

Fancy approach: Pseudo-3D radar
If you want to stick to the "radar" idea, I would suggest presenting the green boxes as kind of flags floating on the radar and with a line indicate their position on some "virtual pseudo-3D radar grid".
Those positions do not necessarily mean any real distance if you cannot get such information. But it could be just a mode of presentation.
Maybe making use of the gyro sensors to influence the displaying even.
If the user "scrolls" -- or turns by swipe or by really turning into the direction -- on the radar towards a group of overlapping event boxes, you can move them apart and show them similarly stacked as in the screenshot. Maybe allow swiping gestures to quickly dismiss unwanted boxes.
As for the coloring... If your hands are bound because of the style guide requirements, you just have to roll with it. Green is not the worst color. If you can tone it down like the background of the "Jon Doe"-box this could help
